# Validate user's credentials supplied during the installation (pre-install)

Tags: powershell, command-line, installanywhere

I'm using InstallAnywhere and due to security reasons, I need to change the Server (our application server) "Log on as" to other user than System.

I'm asking the user during the Pre-Install to supply me with a username (in a format of `<Hostname\Username>` or `<Domain\Username>`) and a password. Now I need to verify these credentials supplied by the user are valid, and if not prompt the same Panel again.

The problem is that with command line using the `net start...` command - I can't supply username & password.

Using the `runas` command - can give it the username as a parameter but not the password. (also - it was stucked on "attempting to start..." and couldn't start the process)

I've also tried PowerShell script which used the `start-service` command, using the `-Credential` parameter, but it didn't work.
another idea - is there a way to verify this using Regedit?

Comment: What rights are required? Local administrative rights on the computer running the script or something else?

Comment: There is a [Test-ADCredential](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Verify-the-Active-021eedea) function in the gallery to make sure the username and password are valid. That doesn't say anything about the users privileges though.

Comment: As for the rights - the only thing i need is that the service will NOT run as the 'Local System Account'. it could be a local Administrator account, or a Domain user with permissions. The customer will set it during the pre-installation phase...